# getting all 2nd level childs of element & for each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I'm trying to implement a plugin called kort [kort plugin , cool thumbs](https://github.com/hakimel/Kort). The problem is that the plugin is coded to work in this way 
all img must be direct children of a div , example

```
<div class="kort">
<img src="my_img.png" />
<img src="my_img.png" />
<img src="my_img.png" />
<img src="my_img.png" />
<img src="my_img.png" />
<.div>
```

but in my case, I need to add a link to the img so the the will look like

```
<div class="kort">
<a href="#"><img src="my_img.png" /><a/>
<a href="#"><img src="my_img.png" /><a/>
<a href="#"><img src="my_img.png" /><a/>
<a href="#"><img src="my_img.png" /><a/>
<a href="#"><img src="my_img.png" /><a/>
<.div>
```

Here the plugins core [core](https://github.com/hakimel/Kort/blob/master/js/kort.js) i think that line 91 is the source of problem but I'm not sure , I tried to edit and modify several part of code but in vain .

Comment: Can you put together a simple, [sscce (short self-contained correct/compilable example)](http://sscce.org/), demo of your problem, at a site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? That way we can see what you're trying and what the errors are.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code here, not link out to it. Find the portion of the plugin that selects the images and post that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you are finding the elements. Instead of looking for the children, you can look for the image tags.

What the code does now:

```
function updateState() {
    elementLeft = element.offsetLeft;
    elementWidth = element.offsetWidth;
    elementChildren = [].slice.call( element.children );
}
```

What you can try to do:

```
function updateState() {
    elementLeft = element.offsetLeft;
    elementWidth = element.offsetWidth;
    elementChildren = [].slice.call( element.getElementsByTagName("img") );
}
```

Comment: THank you Sir , you cant imagine how im grateful now to you , i think that the problem right now is solved , once again thank you sir